# HI please any answer the question

Tags: fields

How can we hide or display fields to two users with same profile, same role and same record types

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @Srikanth. Please give appropriate title to your question.

Comment: You can do it via permission sets. Do not provide access to field via profile, provide it via permission set.

Comment: Valid question but your title must be relevant to the question...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to

1)Disable the access to fields for that profile

2)Create one user group and add users to this group for which you want to give access to those fields.

3)Use Sharing rule to release access to fields for that particular user group.

or

1)Disable the access to fields for that profile

2)Create a permission set to grant access to fields.

3) Assign this permission set to the user you want to give access